# Wordpress reliability

Tags: plugins

I am developing a site with WP 4.5.3 and WAMP. The site is using about 20 plugins from many authors.
Randomly I get changes in pages that make me shiver. For example, just switching from my theme to "twenty fourteen" and reverse, and disabling enabling all my plugins, changed the layout and default template of the homepage!
Randomly the editor will load an older version of a page (occurred 5 times in 4 months).

I am quite scared about this. Wonder what could happen if data gets corrupted somehow or if an ill behaved plugin may corrupt my system.

I do regular backups when a "solid" release is ready, but I wonder what can happen and what can i do to limit risks

Comment: 20 plugins is too many in my opinion.  I would recommend multiple environments and testing any plugin updates on a staging copy of the site before deploying changes to your production site.

Comment: WordPress core is very reliable and robust.  It goes through a rigorous development, test and release process.  All it takes is one poorly written plugin to completely annul that.

Comment: I understand that 20 plugins is a lot (of risks BTW). What are your advice ?

Comment: The number of plugins is *not* relevant, only their quality. Don't install a plugin without a thorough code review.

Comment: Humm.. Code is like building a house... sometimes your code takes un untested branch and bugs will take over.... Not an easy task to inspect code. Suggestions?

Comment: like @CC said, WP is very reliable.  So if you do regular backups of your DB and site files, then you should be safe.  As for your _shiver_. Enabling/DIsabling a theme will affect your layout if, for instance, theme 1 has sidebar X, but theme 2 doesn't, the widget enabled on theme 1 would get disabled for theme 2. Also, WP now saves a copy of your editor content on your computer (which is good if you lose connection) but sometimes, maybe because of network issues, a copy of your content saved locally would be newer then the copy saved to the DB and that's what would be loaded into WP

Comment: Normally, you have a staging site where you can test everything manually and automatically. When you deploy to the live site, you make a complete backup in the first step.

Comment: @toscho, this exactly what I do. I am developing locally on WAMP and release when possible stable version to the production site

Comment: Your live site does very likely not run on WAMP, so your local setup is not a proper staging site. :)

Comment: I am also using a testing WP install online on the same server... But I believe problems may arise regardless the platform..

Comment: If something happens on your live site that didn't happen on the staging site, you 1. roll back everything, 2. fix the staging site, because it is flawed. That's not a WordPress specific problem.

Comment: What kind of code inspection do you perform on plugin's code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The things you describe are certainly signs of a site build that isn't too healthy. What can happen in it? Anything. Who knows.

What are practical steps to get it under control?

There are roughly three components to WP site build: code, generated files (typically uploads), database state (config and content).

You take control of code by using **version control and dependency management** (such as Composer).

Many developers prefer to place hard restrictions on WP so it's unable to write/modify files anywhere other than uploads folder. Dependency management captures and tracks *exact* state of the site's code, rather than ad hoc updates through WP admin.

You take control of generated files and database with **thorough backups**.

You should have these in *any* case anyway. Backups should always be sent off site from where the site is hosted and managed by yourself. Never trust hosting to do backups for you. Having state of the data regularly captured not only saves you when things get broken, but also helps to compare states and trace down content and configuration problems to specific changes.

Comment: Thank for enlightening the route to a safe path. One question : did you ever face partial database corruption, why did it happen and what remedies did you apply?

Comment: As far as I remember I only had issue like that once on a pretty crappy hosting, so it likely was out of my control overall. Don't remember resolution, likely hosting support dealt with it.

Comment: I suspect siteorigin pagebuilder not behaving as expected. Off topic, but do you think it is safe?

Comment: No remote idea.

Comment: Rarst, how can I get in contact with you privately?

Comment: contact@rarst.net